# Is it safe to have an instance variable pointing to activity inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need my application to be compatible with tablets, so I am converting some Activity classes into Fragment classes. However in Activity version of my class I have a lot of `this`, `getSupportActionBar`, `ContextCompat.getColor(this, ...)` which don't work with Fragment, so all my functions start with this statement :

```
final AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
```

And then I replace `this` by `activity`, `getSupportActionBar` by `activity.getSupportActionBar`, etc..

My question is simple : is it memory-leak-safe to have an instance variable in my Fragment class that would store the reference to the activity, in order to avoid to declare `activity` variable in all my methods. The question may seem dummy but I acknowledge that I don't understand very well memory leaks with activities, and I have found so many articles and posts that tell to be careful that I am sort of afraid to misuse Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to replace most cases of `this` with `getActivity()`. Always use this getter because the activity reference can change (for example: orientation change). However, keep in mind the context in which you're calling it. `getActivity()` will return `null` before the fragment is attached and after the fragment is detached. If you keep it within the lifecycle, it should generally be safe.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is safe to do this the more better way is to just use getActivity() don't make any reference.

Comment: OK thanx, actually calling getActivity() everywhere makes my code very ugly, especially when I have to cast it.

Comment: i can understand dear.